# How to create nullable variable in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I created a model class, this is one of my a variable in model class

```
Datetime hotel_effect_open_date
```

but JSON response hotel_effect_open_date is null, getting an error in my application. and I modified to DateTime to String, it's working. In API created in the .net core, it looks like this,

```
Nullable<DateTime> hotel_effect_open_date
```

How to create a nullable variable in DART language?

Comment: everything is nullable in dart

Comment: Non-nullable support is work in progress https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/nullable

Answer (score 37):

Now Dart is in the process of redesigning its type system. So that expression of that type can be either **nullable** or **non-nullable**. Something like this:
`type? variable; // variable can be null.`
Example:

```dart
int? a; // a can now be null.
```

**Reference**: [Dart nullability syntax decision](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-nullability-syntax-decision-a-b-or-a-b-d827259e34a3)

Comment: wow, just like in Kotlin. All these languages are just tending towards one style.

Answer (score 10):

TLDR:

```
int? aNullableInt = null;
```

---

Detailed explanation:

**Dart 2... and above**

documentation:
https://dart.dev/null-safety

> With null safety, all of the variables in the following code are
> non-nullable:
>
> // In null-safe Dart, none of these can ever be null.

```
var i = 42; // Inferred to be an int.
String name = getFileName();
final b = Foo();
```

> **To indicate that a variable might have the value null, just add ? to**
> **its type declaration:**

```
int? aNullableInt = null;
```

**Dart <2**

```dart
DateTime example;
example = null;
```

Uninitialized variables have an initial value of `null`. Even variables with numeric types are initially `null`, because numbers—like everything else in Dart—are objects.

```dart
int lineCount;
assert(lineCount == null);
```

Comment: This is the older way to create null.  The new (Flutter 2) way is something like:
`int? lineCount;`  Now lineCount can be an int or be null.

Answer (score 0):

you can create nullable variable like this for example:

```dart
int? a;
a = 4
```

sometimes you want to use type inference to be nullable, for example:

```dart
/// here a is of type int
var a = 1;
/// here b type is int?
var b = 1.nullable

extension<T extends Object> on T {
  T? get nullable => this;
}
```